# xmonad will behave abnormally if compiled with "ghc -threaded"

Tags: haskell, xmonad

The xmonad created using `xmonad --recompile` works great. However, if we build xmonad using 'ghc -threaded xmonad.hs` and changing its name according to your platform i.e.  xmonad-i386-freebsd, then xmonad will behave abnormally.

.some key definitions will not work.

.XMonad.Actions.GridSelect will not spawn applications
...

Any suggestion is appreciated !

Comment: Why don't you ask on their mailing list or IRC channel?

Comment: yes i have . Up to now, it seems that thread RTS doesnot work normally on some platform.

Comment: Why are you trying to use --threaded? it is not supported by X11

Answer (score 4):

Xmonad doesn't support --threaded as the X11 C library is not thread safe.

Comment: the `ghc -threaded` created xmonad works except its spawn function. At lease i have not found other problems.

Comment: It 'works' as there are no instances of `forkIO` in any of xmonad's code or extensions, as the underlying X11 library is not threadsafe.